# How common was Nixon-esque espionage in 20th-century American politics?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, political-history

During the [Watergate scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watergate_scandal), President Nixon's supporters were reportedly [fond of saying](https://www.kansascity.com/opinion/opn-columns-blogs/syndicated-columnists/article187662578.html), "Everyone does it." When I listened to *Slate*'s [Slow Burn podcast](https://slate.com/podcasts/slow-burn/s1/watergate) recently, I remember them saying that his supporters claimed that Presidents Roosevelt and Truman had spied on their opponents.

Yet even prior to the scandal, the public considered Nixon's campaign and broader circle to be more willing to engage in [dirty tricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratfucking) than other political actors of the time. Then again, President Johnson used his government to [spy on the Goldwater campaign](https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2018/05/22/cia-fbi-spy-presidential-campaign-trump-goldwater-218415/). To me, that seems like a more severe abuse of power than anything Nixon did. Whether you agree or not is immaterial.

My question is, how common were dirty tricks like this in American politics at the time? Were Nixon and Johnson aberrations, or were Nixon's supporters correct in viewing such hijinks as normal for the time?

Comment: Whether clean or dirty, said tricks must first and foremost serve the interests of the nation, rather than one's own; perhaps that was the difference ?

Comment: @Lucian Perhaps that was the difference *claimed* by the actors, but it's not a difference at all. Nixon would 100% have claimed that he did it because he was better qualified to be president and therefore the tricks were in the country's interest. Everyone always has excuses for bad behavior. The nature of the excuses are not very interesting to me for the purposes of this question.

Comment: “A thief believes everybody steals.”

― [E. W. Howe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._W._Howe)

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude: I was referring to public perception, not about one's opinion of oneself.

Comment: @Lucian If you can find examples of one side or another claiming that their side's dirty tricks were both completely fine and not in service of the public good, while a different side claimed that their side's tricks were in service of the public good, I imagine that would form part of a good answer. But I'm *extremely* doubtful that that would be the case, and it would only be a part of the answer in any event.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude: I was referring to the widespread public perception of the general population, not about biased partisan opinion of one's own side, by what I assume to be a small minority of die-hard supporters.

Comment: @Lucian The majority probably had no knowledge of these acts, other than of Watergate. I highly doubt a good answer will make any use of the "widespread public perception" of the various acts.

Comment: There are *facts* and *perceptions*. One may have good reasons to believe that there are no such things as *honest politicians* or *fair politics*, but claiming that this is the case without evidence (or only with an evidence coming from another interested party) is   *conspiracy theory.* Nixon was caught and, importantly, both Democrats and (the majority of) Republicans have agreed on it.

Comment: Define "espionage" or "dirty tricks" - what is common in one generation/election is scandalous in the next.  All politics is corrupt, always has been.  From the manipulation of the first electoral college to Madison's opponents attempts to disqualify him from the Senate, to the skullduggery deployed for and against constitutional ratification.  Any winner take all contest with unbounded opportunities for graft will attract techniques that one side will declare "crafty" and the other side will declare "dirty tricks".  Victors write history.

Comment: @MCW I take your point, but I think we can limit it to illegal acts, either committed against the opposing campaign or aiming to manipulate the result of the election, sanctioned or covered up by high-level members of the campaign or by elected officials affiliated with the campaign. How does that sound as a working definition?

Comment: The examples I gave were aimed to manipulate the results of the election; one could argue whether they were sanctioned.  What about [Phillip Freneau](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poets/philip-freneau)?  A full time propagandist employed manipulate elections, on the payroll of the US Secretary of State, paid for duties he was not qualified to carry out.  Dirty tricks from the first presidency.

Answer (score 6):

I would say there was a level of corruption in politics in the 20 years prior to Nixon's second run for President.  Such things as the shady vote count when Johnson won his Senate seat. Or the Nixon-Kennedy election, Of course all of these are allegations and never proven in a court of law.

"A study of Lyndon B. Johnson provides new evidence that the 36th President stole his first election to the United States Senate, in 1948...Mr. Caro maintains that although ballot fraud was common in the late 1940's in some parts of Texas, the Johnson campaign of 1948 raised it to a new level. Mr. Caro supports his charge with an interview with Luis Salas, an election judge in Jim Wells County who said he acknowledged his role only after all others involved in the theft had died."  [Source: NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/1990/02/11/us/how-johnson-won-election-he-d-lost.html)

Another well known instance of (alleged) corruption was JFKs win over Nixon.

"But historian Robert Dallek, who wrote definitive biographies of JFK and LBJ,, concluded that Daley’s storied political machine “probably stole Illinois from Nixon”—though he reminds readers that Kennedy “would have won even without Illinois.” FBI agents who had placed wire taps on key Daley lieutenants (for entirely unrelated purposes) also had reason to believe that Illinois was rigged." [Source: Politico](https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2016/10/donald-trump-2016-rigged-nixon-kennedy-1960-214395/)

And this doesn't even get into pre-ww2 elections where there are plenty of alleged instances of outright voter fraud, intimidation, and the like.

If you have the time to read, please check out this article, that talks a bit about the EH Crump political machine in TN.  GI's fresh back from the war tried to run a legit campaign and were totally cheated.  They reacted like any fresh soldier would and laid siege to the town and basically initiated what would now be called a local coup d'etat that ended in deaths and explosions and the works.  It is a fascinating piece of history.

*[Wikipedia:Battle_of_Athens_(1946)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Athens_(1946))*

Comment: Robert Caro's reporting surpasses everything else. LBJ stole the 1948 primary and there is zero reason to doubt it. As for Daley: I grew up under him, and the desired vote totals in Chicago were targets handed to the precinct captains. However, the rest of Illinois was Republican and they may well have cheated for Nixon.